# autocomplete on several fields at the same time

Tags: autocomplete, primefaces

I have a Database managed entity called `myPerson`.
It contains a lot of attributes, but also two names attributes :  `firstname`, `lastname`

I want to use autocomplete to selecte `myPerson`objects from the database.
The user should be able to type the firstname or the lastname and it should make suggestions of persons with the input data as their first name or last name.
Then when the user press submit, the selected myPersone shall be fully retrieved from the database (it is not fully loaded at the beginning for performance issue)

So I have

```
<p:autoComplete minQueryLength="3" value="#{myBean.autoCompleteValue}" effect="fade" completeMethod=#{myBean.autoComplete}" forceSelection="true"/>
```

Then in myBean :
I load at initialization the first names and last names in a list of strings (I do not load all the `myPerson` objects for performance issue.
Then my auto complete method looks like that

```
public List<String> autoComplete(String prefix) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        if ((prefix == null) || (prefix.length() == 0)) {
            // safety nets
            // do nothing
        } else {
            Iterator<String> iterator = names.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String elem = ((String) iterator.next());
                if (elem.toLowerCase().indexOf(prefix.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                    result.add(elem);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This works fine. When the user types the beginning of a first name OR a last name, it gets suggested in the dropdown menu of the autocomplete component.

My problem lies in what comes after. How can I load the selected `myPerson` from the database.
The autocomplete value will be stored in `#{myBean.autoCompleteValue}` 
But then I don't know anymore if the user typed a first name or a last name. I cannot efficiently searched in the database, and I would have to perform a search by first name, and if i'm not lucky a search by last name.

Do you know how this could be achieved more nicely ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct another class, e.g. `MyPersonTransfer` which only contains firstname, lastname and the data-base id. Then use this class (instead of `String`) as a return type for your `autoComplete()` method and everywhere else (e.g. `value="#{myBean.autoCompleteValue}"`).
This way you also save the db `id` which you can then use to load the complete person once it was chosen.